# Why is the output of my limit expression an interval?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why is the output of the limit below an interval? It should be precisely $1$.

```
Limit[(2/Pi) ((2 n + 2)!!/(2 n + 1)!!) Integrate[(1 - x^2)^(n + 1/2), {x, 0, 1}],
   n -> Infinity]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have made an assumption without telling *Mathematica* about it. Namely, that $n$ is an integer. You can add this assumption like so:

```
Limit[(2 (2n + 2)!! Integrate[(1 - x^2)^(n + 1/2), 
          {x, 0, 1}])/(Pi(2n + 1)!!), n -> Infinity, 
   Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
```

Comment: thank you for your explanations!

Comment: Without this assumption it appears that the correct interval of fluctuation is 2/Pi to 1. `Limit[]` is unable to completely sort out the dependencies of the various fluctuating components. I think it comes reasonably close though; if you blindly plug in for `n` an interval of length 2Pi, for large n, the interval range that results is far bigger.

Comment: @Daniel Using `FunctionExpand` on the expression first gives `{2/Pi, 1}`.  Does `FunctionExpand` do any transformations that are not generally valid?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think it does anything invalid. I had used FunctionExpand myself, but maybe I'm not using it in the same way or place you did.

Comment: @Danel I used it as `Limit[FunctionExpand[(2/
     Pi) ((2 n + 2)!!/(2 n + 1)!!) Integrate[(1 - x^2)^(n + 1/2), {x, 
     0, 1}]], n -> \[Infinity]]`  I was just wondering why `Limit` doesn't try to use it itself.  But how these symbolic functions can choose a strategy to calculate something is a big mystery to me :)  It must be quite complicated and difficult to get right.